# error 'cannot covert [class] to int' in micropython

Tags: micropython

I was trying to use a function from my own class and it gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robot/MyBlocks/main.py", line 134, in <module>
  File "/home/robot/MyBlocks/main.py", line 50, in drive_mm
TypeError: can't convert Generic_Myblocks to int

Exited with error code 1.
```

Here's my code for the drive function:

```
def drive_mm(angle, speed, mm, brake=True):
  robot.reset()
  while robot.distance() < mm:
    robot.drive(speed, angle)       <-- the error is this line
  robot.stop()
  if brake == True:
    lm.hold()
    rm.hold()
    return
  else:
    lm.brake()
    rm.brake()
```

And for the actual program:

```
# Creates a object using the custom class and runs the drive function off it
    myblocks = Generic_Myblocks(ev3, robot, leftMotor, rightMotor, leftColor, rightColor, infrared)
    myblocks.drive_mm(0, 1000, 100)
```

Comment: `robot` is undefined (in the posted code).

Comment: robot was defined as the DriveBase() object earlier in the code. I can show you more if you'd like.

Comment: `drive_mm()` appears to be a method of the class, in which case the first parameter it receives will be the instance of the class it was invoked via.  That parameter is normally named `self` - you are instead receiving it as `angle`, and trying to do math with it.

Comment: That seems to be it @jasonharper. thank you all, im kinda new to this stuff